# Android Issue with Binary XML file line #1

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

My app was working great with Android 4.0+ now i want to make it compatible with older versions, i imported the complete support library extended the activity to `ActionBarActivity` and then changed everything to `getSupportActionBar` and used the `app.v4.Fragment`. Eclipse is not showing any error in the code but when i start the app it shows the SplashScreen and then FC.

```
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1456)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1821)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:686)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:754)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1656)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1286)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7184)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:714)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7184)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7184)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7184)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7184)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7184)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1143)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1862)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    ... 35 more
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x10102fd a=-1}
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1719)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:453)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:446)
03-31 13:47:25.104: E/AndroidRuntime(25142):    ... 38 more
```

This is the XML of the main activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff">
             <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#069"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the code for the Adapter

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String coment;
    public String img;
    public int imga;
    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public void addItems(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        if(data != null) {
             data.addAll(arraylist);  
        } else {
             data = arraylist;
        }
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView quien;
        ImageView imagen;
        TextView reporte;
        TextView fecha;
        VideoView video;
        ImageView imgs;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        imagen = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
        fecha = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fecha);
        quien = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quien);
        reporte = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.reporte);
        video = (VideoView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.videos);
        imgs = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgs);
        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
     // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.IMAGEN), imagen);
        fecha.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.FECHA));
        reporte.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.CONTENIDOPOST));
        quien.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.QUIEN));

        if (resultp.get(MainActivity.VIDEO).length() != 0){
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.IMGS), imgs);

            final String videoplayer = resultp.get(MainActivity.VIDEO);

            if (resultp.get(MainActivity.CONTENIDOPOST).length() == 0){
                reporte.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            imgs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            imgs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(videoplayer));
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }

        if (resultp.get(MainActivity.IMGS).length() != 0 && resultp.get(MainActivity.VIDEO).length() <= 5){
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.IMGS), imgs);
            final String imagenview = resultp.get(MainActivity.IMGS);
            imgs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (resultp.get(MainActivity.CONTENIDOPOST).length() == 0){
                reporte.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            imgs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    /*
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(imagenview), "image/*");
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    */
                    Intent intentBrowseFiles = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intentBrowseFiles.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(imagenview), "image/*");
                    //intentBrowseFiles.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intentBrowseFiles);

                }
            });

        }


        // Capture ListView item click

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Get the position
                resultp = data.get(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MenuContextual.class);
                    // Pass all data rank

                    //intent.putExtra("imagen", resultp.get(MainActivity.IMAGEN));

                    intent.putExtra("quien_id", resultp.get(MainActivity.QUIEN_ID));

                    intent.putExtra("reporte", resultp.get(MainActivity.CONTENIDOPOST));

                    intent.putExtra("quien", resultp.get(MainActivity.QUIEN));

                    intent.putExtra("fecha", resultp.get(MainActivity.FECHA));
                    // Start SingleItemView Class
                    context.startActivity(intent);



            }
        });

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be a problem with your adapter. Can you post adapter code ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the adapter code is in the OP, i just updated

Comment: This is not the adapter. The stacktrace is about an `ArrayAdapter` - show where you instantiate it.

Comment: try to run lint as well with your code

Comment: can you please provide full stacktrace ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay my power went off (Venezuela) and still without electrical power at home. As soon as I get back I will publish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Then you add ActionBarCompat to google's Navigation Drawer sample do not forget change native methods to SupportMethods: getActionBar() -> getSupportActionBar(); **invalidateOptionsMenu() -> supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();** ..."

did you changed the bold text also ? :)

try read this topic : [android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685278/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-1-error-inflating-class-u)